# Can I get all the studio's detail from Mindbody to my application through the MindBody API?

Tags: ios, mindbody

I am working on an app where I need to integrate the MindBody API, and I have accessed it successfully, but the problem is that I am not sure whether I can get only my studio related data or all the studio related data which are available on MindBody Website.

I have registered on MindBody website and got login credential for developer like:

**username:** `Siteowner`

**password:** `abc`

I have also downloaded sample iOS code from https://github.com/arrak-rukkharat/API-Integration-iOS and inserted my credential and it's working well.

But the main thing is I want all the studio's data not only mine. So is it possible? Can I get all the studio's data through this API call?
Please provide me any sources related to this confusion.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything depends on which exactly data you what to request using API.

You should be able to get **limited information of any studio** using your dev credentials only, sending them as **SourceCredentials** in your API requests.

You need to be **granted access** by the studios to **get all information** (available with API) **for any studio**, sending **also UserCredentials** in you API requests - these are either your developer credentials (but username is with underscore in the beggining) or the studio's staff/owner user credentials.

More information about authentication (how to be granted access),  SourceCredentials and UserCredentials is available in : [Mindbodyonline documentation](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Documentation/Authentication)

The other useful source is a list of API methods that provides an overview of each method. Normally a method that requires UserCredentials is marked with a line 'This requires a staff credentials' or similar. For example take a look at   [ClassService.UpdateClientVisits()](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/Documentation/ClassService)  documentation. Methods that aren't marked with such line should provide you information for any studio without any additional authentication except your dev credentials (SourceCredentials).

Comment: Thanks yuga for your valuable reply. yes i know I need to provide my credential to call MindBody API and as a response  I can get my studio related data. the same thing I want to do with other studios so should i need to pass these studios credential while calling API ? or is there any other ways to get others studios data ? I am sorry that I am asking you very silly questions but I am really confused about MindBoody so please if you can explain it then its really helpful for me.

Comment: Pankaj, I've extended my response to be more precise and contain more details - I suppose now it definitely answers the list of the questions you've sent.

Comment: yes Yuga now I got the point and thanks for for replay. I have made some R&D on the link previously you have provided and its make my doubts clear . so thanks for your replay.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer did help you, feel free to accept it, though up to you of course.

Comment: hi Yuga, again I am stuck at this mind body API so I thought you might help me. actually I got that point that I need to involve with other studios to get their data by **username** and **password** but I have one question in my mind that what should I need to pass in  **UserCredentials**  if I am involve with multiple studios? like I want all the studios data as well as mine then what should need to I need to pass in user's site id and credential ? because  I have multiple **Site Id** now. please guide me if you can and thanks for your time.

Comment: Once you've got and used an activation code/link (or studio owner made activation with this code/link for you, as it requires at least staff or owner rights in MINDBODY), after that you can get any info sending your dev credentials (username underscored, e.g. _yourDevUser).